# Why do some domains resolve to localhost?

Tags: networking, dns, localhost

So I happened to input "blue.com" into the browser to see if the domain was available. It timed out immediately, which I thought was odd, so I used tracert in the Windows console and saw it was equivalent to inputting localhost (resolves to 127.0.0.1).

It may be worth noting that green.com resolves to nothing, and is registered by MarkMonitor Inc, where blue.com is registered by Domain The Net Technologies Ltd. Both are domain management companies.

I cannot find anything online about this at all. Can anyone explain why blue.com resolves to localhost while other domains do not?

Comment: `blue.com` resolves to `127.0.0.1` so nothing surprising in the behavior you observe. Any name can resolve to localhost, this is the responsibility of the zone/name owner. But other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: All you have done in commenting is reiterate my question as a statement, and tell me I have chosen the wrong community. If this is so, feel free to point me in the right direction. So far this is the best site on StackOverflow I can find for this question.

Comment: "All you have done in commenting is reiterate my question as a statement" What a misleading statement.. you **edited** your question AFTER my comment to "surprisingly" add in your question what I said in my comment that you were obviously not aware of before. "So far this is the best site on StackOverflow I can find for this question. " You may want to read again https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to better understand what is on topic here or not. Your question has nothing to do with programming and is hence offtopic.

Comment: " Can anyone explain why blue.com resolves to localhost while other domains do not?" Why not? Owners of names are free to make them resolves in any way they like, why do that trouble you in any way?

Comment: No Patrick, I edited the question to make it more clear so that I could avoid comments like yours in the future. 

As for whether this is on-topic, it is possible that it could be considered off-topic. However, there was not a _better_ alternative that I could find. If no community makes this question on-topic, I have to post the question where my judgement leads. 

It seems your answer was meant to be "Any domain can be made by the registrar to resolve to any IP address". Given this and my related research, I will edit my post name and write an answer.

Comment: "However, there was not a better alternative that I could find.". So if you don't find a place to post your question, then it is automatically on-topic to post it on Stack Overflow? No, I don't think so...

Comment: " It seems your answer was meant to be "Any domain can be made by the registrar to resolve to any IP address"." No, not at all, this is not what I said and it shows also how you don't understand how the DNS works. First I did not write an answer, but just a comment, because your question is STILL offtopic here. The purpose of the comment was trying to help you phrase your question better and where it makes sense, but unfortunately you didn't took that advice. Second, registrars are (mostly) not involved with the resolution, that concerns the DNS provider used for the domain.2 different things.

Comment: "yet this answer which you are proud of stackoverflow.com/questions/49075381/… is somehow more on-topic and has anything to do with programming?" Not all questions are equally interesting and worth answering... But thanks to have checked my answers, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: "Actually I do understand how it works" This is doubtful, from someone saying "so I used tracert in the Windows console" when debugging a DNS problem, or "Any domain can be made by the registrar to resolve to any IP address"  showing the misconception on what a registrar does or does not, related to DNS resolution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246176/discussion-between-blue-dev-and-patrick-mevzek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any domain name can be registered to "point" or "resolve" to any IP address. This is done using what is called an "A Record" or "Address Record". Various other kinds of records can be found [here](https://simpledns.plus/help/dns-record-types).

In short, when someone registers a domain name as an "Address Record", they can choose any IP address they wish, including "127.0.0.1". Why Domain The Net Technologies chose to do so is something only they know, but technically there could be any number of domains which point to that address.

To learn more about how domain name servers work internally, check out [this site](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/build-your-own-name-server) which explains how you can make one yourself.